# Why does interface error is given when Realm Object is extended to model class.?

Tags: android, database, realm

I am creating realm Database. Created the model and extended with `RealmObject`. It gives me error that

> Cannot be cast to io.realm.FooRealmProxyInterface.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer. Just add Open keyword in Model class so that all classes of realm object can access that model class.